# get_role('administrator') retornando null

Tags: wordpress

Em um projeto usando wordpress tem um plugin que está dando erro em uma chamada a função `get_role`.

```
$admin = get_role( 'administrator' );
```

Isso retorna `null` e então em `$admin->add_cap('regra')` da um fatal error.

É como se o wordpress tivesse perdido a regra de administrador.

Já procurei de várias formas por uma solução para isso mas não acho.

Comment: O site tem usuários ativos com esse role? Se tiver pode ser só questão de recriar no banco.

Comment: Ele tem sim a permissão. Como eu poderia recriar isso no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o site tem usuários ativos como administradores mas o role foi editado no banco ou removido, algo assim pode resolver ou pelo menos ajudar a entender o problema.

No `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    // Imprime os roles existentes, pra conferir os role que já existem
    var_dump( wp_roles() );

    // Imprime o objeto WP_Role se foi criado, null se já existia
    var_dump( add_role( 'administrator', 'Administrator' ) );
} );
```

A partir daqui você pode recriar as capabilities:

```
// Reseta as capabilities básicas do WP
// CUIDADO: se o seu código tiver retirado capabilities de algum 
// role elas podem retornar se você rodar assim.
populate_roles();

// Se precisar adicionar capabilities de forma mais granular, 
// use esse formato:
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'activate_plugins' ); // repetir com todas as caps desejadas
```

Só precisa rodar isso uma vez. Confira os resultados na tela, depois pode tirar do functions de novo.

[Aqui uma lista das capabilities padrão para cada nível de usuário.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: Realmente a role administrator não aparecia no primeiro var dump e depois começou a aparecer. No entanto ao logar, sou redirecionado para o site e não para o painel. Depois tentando acessar /wp-admin aparecer a mensagem "Sem permissão para acessar esta página."

Como é uma nova role, eu teria que dar todas as capacidades de uso para ela com a função add_cap() ?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com o código pra recriar as capabilities. Numa lida rápida do core eu achei que elas seriam recriadas automaticamente mas foi engano, `populate_roles()` só roda em upgrades.

Comment: Fiz utilizando a segunda opção usando add_cap com toda a lista de caps para o administrador. O uso da função populate_roles() deu um erro informando que a função não existe.